# 'Gradle cucumber' With testImplementation Not Working

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber

I am building a simple test app that uses cucumber. Unfortunately '**gradle cucumber**' throws errors when I try to run it. However everything runs fine when  I change testImplement to the deprecated testCompile in build.gradle. Is this expected behaviour? What would I have to do to get cucumber to run using testImplementation?

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:4.2.0'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:4.2.0'
}

configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber', 'src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

Result (Error):

```
> Task :cucumber FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.cli.Main
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:4.2.0'
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:4.2.0'
}
...
```

Result (Works):

```
> Task :cucumber
No features found at [src/test/resources]

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
```

Can someone explain what is going on here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) which says that testRuntime is deprecated

> The compile, testCompile, runtime and testRuntime configurations inherited from the Java plugin are still available but are deprecated

I think it should be

```
configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testImplementation
    }
}
```